# I want to limit the number of taps

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer

Each tap adds an object on my scene, but I want to add it only once and then disable the Tap gesture. I looked everywhere but none of them are working with my code. Can someone help me with this? Either limiting the tap to 1 only or disabling it. I tried adding the tap gesture as Outlet and then setting .isEnabled = false but it is still not working.

```
class ARScene: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var sceneView: ARSCNView!




var tap : UITapGestureRecognizer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   self.sceneView.debugOptions = [ARSCNDebugOptions.showFeaturePoints, ARSCNDebugOptions.showWorldOrigin]
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

    self.sceneView.session.run(configuration)

    // Set the view's delegate
    sceneView.delegate = self

    sceneView.debugOptions = [ARSCNDebugOptions.showFeaturePoints]

    // Show statistics such as fps and timing information
    sceneView.showsStatistics = true

    // Create a new scene
    // let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!

    // Set the scene to the view
    //sceneView.scene = scene

    registerGestureRecognizer()



}

func registerGestureRecognizer(){
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

}



@objc func handleTap(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer){

    //let touchLocation = gestureRecognizer.location(in: sceneView)
    let sceneLocation = gestureRecognizer.view as! ARSCNView
    let touchLocation = gestureRecognizer.location(in: sceneLocation)
    let hitResult = self.sceneView.hitTest(touchLocation, types: [.existingPlaneUsingExtent, .estimatedHorizontalPlane])

    if hitResult.count > 0 {

        guard let hitTestResult = hitResult.first else{
            return
        }


        let node = SCNNode()
        let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/bucket/Bucket2.scn")


        let nodeArray = scene!.rootNode.childNodes

        for childNode in nodeArray{

            node.addChildNode(childNode as SCNNode)
        }


        let worldPos = hitTestResult.worldTransform
        node.scale = SCNVector3Make(0.009,0.009,0.009);
        node.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: worldPos.columns.3.y, z: -1.4)

        sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
        tap.isEnabled = false //NOT WORKING, I want to stop tap gesture here

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false ?

Comment: I don't want all Interactions disabled, only the tap one because in my game I also have swipe gestures.

Comment: check my answer let me know if still stuck

Comment: how about removing the gesture after the tap? Also your action selection should be action: #selector(handleTap:) (with colon at the end) so the gesture can be passed to the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to disable your tapGesture you need to have reference to the same gesture instance you assign tap to. 
There are two ways either create global instance so you can change its properties like Enable/Disable from anywhere
Or access the variable from the action/method for that gesture.

Create the global varibale for your tap 
like

```
var tap: UITapGestureRecognizer! // global varibale

func registerGestureRecognizer(){
   tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGesture(_:))) 
   tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
   sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
```

and then disable this in taphandle

```
tap.isEnabled = false // disable the gesture
```

Or

2 Update your handle methods to

```
@objc func handleTap(withTapRecognizer tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
  ........
   tapGesture.isEnabled = false // use the instance variable and disable the gesture this will disable the gesture from which its been called
}
```

Comment: For global variable the error is: Type 'UITapGestureRecognizer?' has no member 'isEnabled'. As for the handle method the error is: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1)

Comment: are you sure you are using the same variable? you need to update your registerGestureRecognizer method also

Comment: Corrected, now I am getting this: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: post the code I can't tell without knowing what you are doing wrong, Did you updated your handle methods also

Comment: I updated the code, trying the global variable, can you please check.

Comment: In your registerGestureRecognizer you are not using global variable but creatig new update that

Comment: Omg, yes. THANK YOU! You saved me! I apologise for not seeing the global var change in my registerGestureRecognizer. :D

Answer (score 0):

For you to access the gesture in the function, you need to initialize it using

```
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(gestureRecognizer:)))
```

Then in your handleTap method, you can this at the end of the function

```
    gestureRecognizer.view?.removeGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
```

Comment: It is giving me this error: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

Comment: I've update the initializing of the gesture. It should work now.